# PostgreSQL: Index is used - but not when querying with LIMIT OFFSET

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, indexing

Let's say I have a `messages` table in a PostgreSQL database that contains many entries. The primary key of the table is just a simple `serial` column (like `int` but with "auto increment").

Then I want to select the TOP-25 messages that a user received and that meet certain criteria. The result is ordered by the unique primary key column (`msgid DESC`).

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT msgid, msgtype, created, msgtitle, recvuser, readbyrecv, someothercolumn, onemorecolumn
FROM xyz.messages 
WHERE ( ( msgtype = 42 ) OR ( msgtype = 1337 ) ) 
  AND ( recvuser = 123 ) AND ( hiddenbyrecv = false ) 
ORDER BY msgid DESC 
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

I have a filtered index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_abcde
ON xyz.messages
USING btree (msgtype, recvuser, hiddenbyrecv, msgid DESC)
WHERE (msgtype = 42 OR msgtype = 1337) AND hiddenbyrecv = false;
```

I think the index should include all the columns that are used in the `WHERE` and `ORDER` clauses.

If I run the SELECT *without* the `LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0` (that line commented out), the index is being used and the query is *very* fast (about 2ms):

```
-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT msgid, msgtype, created, msgtitle, recvuser, readbyrecv, someothercolumn, onemorecolumn
FROM xyz.messages 
WHERE ( ( msgtype = 42 ) OR ( msgtype = 1337 ) ) 
  AND ( recvuser = 123 ) AND ( hiddenbyrecv = false ) 
ORDER BY msgid DESC 
-- LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

But if I query *with* the LIMIT and OFFSET clause (see first SQL query), it scans the primary key of the table backwards and performs a full table scan. The index is not used. The query takes more than **100 times longer** (> 200ms).

As `msgid` is unique (primary key), I think PostgreSQL should be able to deterministically find the TOP 25 entries ordered by this column just using the index. I've included the only ORDER BY column in the index in the correct order.

What point do I miss? Can you give me some hints?

//Edit: The server runs the standard PostgreSQL 9.4 version package from the Debian repository.

Comment: DID you run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the table after creating the index?

Comment: `VACUUM ANALYZE` didn't change the situation. I've executed it again now. -> The index is used perfectly when querying without `LIMIT 25 OFSET 0`. And I just have to append `LIMIT 25` (not even `OFFSET 0`) to make it ignore the index and the query take more than a hundred times longer.